# How to update one table and returning from related table in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two table: users and stores. 'store' in users is a foreign key related to 'id' of stores.

```
select * from users;
id | username | store
1  | test     | NULL

select * from stores;
id | name
```

Now I try to update 'username' in users and return info of stores related to the id.

```
UPDATE
  users
SET
  username = 'something new'
FROM
  stores
WHERE
  users.id = 2 AND
  users.store = stores.id
RETURNING
  users.id,
  users.username,
  stores.id as "storeId",
  stores.name as "storeName"
```

It doesn't work, and the user cannot be found. It only works when no store in the query.

```
UPDATE
  users
SET
  username = 'something new'
WHERE
  users.id = 2
RETURNING
  users.id,
  users.username
```

What can I do if I want to store info returned by update query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the second update and use the store id in the users table:

```
with u as (
      update users
          set username = 'something new'
      where users.id = 2
      returning *
    )
select store
from u;
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot 'WITH'. Thanks a lot